# Microsoft Dynamics CRM - Annotation(Note) entity's filesize attribute vs set filesize limit for attachments in Email tab

Tags: annotations, dynamics-crm, settings, attachment, filesize

I have been recently working on creating Annotations(Notes/Attachments) in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016. I have noticed that there are different settings for attachment file size as below.

1. In the Settings **Email** tab which is ranging from **0** through **131,072 kilobytes**

   > Microsoft Dynamics CRM -> Settings -> System Settings -> Email -> Set
   >   file size limit for attachments -> Maximum file size (in kilobytes)
2. The Organization entity's "**MaxUploadFileSize**" field setting which is ranging from **0** through **2,147,483,647 Bytes**
3. The Annotation(Note) entity's "**FileSize**" field setting which is ranging from **0** through **1,000,000,000 Bytes**. The description says it's "**File Size (Bytes) of Note**". Does this mean that it's only applies to attachments uploaded against Notes?

The [Annotation Entity Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334398.aspx) specifies as below:

> The maximum size of files that can be uploaded is determined by the Organization.MaxUploadFileSize property. This property is set in the Email tab of the System Settings in the Dynamics 365 application. This setting limits the size of files that can be attached to email messages, notes, and web resources. The default setting is 5 MB.

I suppose "**Organization.MaxUploadFileSize**" is the global setting and any other specific settings as in **Email** or **Notes** take precedence over it for corresponding entities. But this behavior is different from the above documentation.

Could anyone please clarify whether all these settings are interrelated and if so then what's the order of preference among them.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one setting in all this. To clarify:

1. As the MSDN documentation quote says, the `Organization.MaxUploadFileSize` defines the maximum size of a file that you can attach to an annotation or an email message. That's the one setting you can define or change.
2. The user interface to set `Organization.MaxUploadFileSize` is located at the bottom of the `Email` tab under `System Settings` (where you found it).
3. Valid values for `Organization.MaxUploadFileSize` are in the range of 0 to 131072 KB.
4. The `FileSize` field of the `Annotation` entity is not a setting, it's the actual size (in bytes) of a specific attachment in one specific annotation record. The field is populated once you upload (attach) a file.

   To see an example, create a note somewhere (for example under an account or a contact) and attach a file to it. Now open `Advanced Find` and search for annotations. If you add the FileSize column to the output you'll see the size of the file you attached.

Comment: Thanks @Atzmon for the info. Though the `Annotation` entity's `FileSize` is a read-only field, it's range is being shown as **0 - 1,000,000,000 Bytes** under 

`Microsoft Dynamics CRM -> Settings -> Customizations -> Customize the System -> Components -> Entities -> Note -> Fields -> filesize -> Business Rules -> General -> Type`.

The same is the case with `Organization.MaxUploadFileSize` Business Rules section as well. Could you please explain what does these rules specify?

Comment: The `FileSize` field has a type of int with some upper bound set to it but you don't populate the field's value yourself. It's populated when you attach a file. The maximum size of a file you can attach is governed by the MaxUploadFileSize setting, with a range that is far below the upper bound of that int field.